# Transparent PNG in PictureBox

Tags: c#, transparency, picturebox

I am trying to make simple app that allows one to compare image to transparent PNG templates, by dragging the template over picture. For this I need a way to create a PictureBox that will contain the PNG image and be transparent where the the png is transparent.
Everything works fine but the transparency part: When I load a PNG image to the PictureBox (background color is set to transparent) it shows the background color of  the containing panel rather than the image that it hovers.

I searched but only found a way to make the PictureBox completely transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to make a control that is partially transparent.

What you should do is handle the lower `PictureBox`'s `Paint` event (the one that does not need to be transparent), and draw the overlay image using `e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, x, y)`.  This will draw transparent and semi-transparent images correctly.

**EDIT**: In response to your comment, there's nothing wrong with calling the `Invalidate` method in the `MouseMove` event.  However, you will notice some flickering.  To solve the flickering, make a control that inherits `PictureBox`, and call `SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffered, true)` in the constructor.

Comment: the problem is the dragging - Woudn't be preformance disaster if i need to redraw the image on every pixel movemnt of the mouse?

Comment: To solve the flickering, in most cases, I find that Update(); does a better job.

Comment: @lucifer: Calling `Update()` will not reduce flickering.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine if you add the pictureBoxOnTop to the list of controls of the pictureBoxToBeHovered to be hovered.

```
        pictureBoxToBeHovered.Controls.Add(pictureBoxOnTop);
        pictureBoxOnTop.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        pictureBoxOnTop .Location = new Point(0,0) ;
```